# What does the Windows flag in the Linux logo of kernel 3.11 mean?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

I've just installed kernel-3.11.0-1.fc20 for my Fedora 19 installation. During the rebooting progress, I saw the Linux logo with a Windows flag in it, what does it mean?
[image: a Windows flag in Linux logo of Linux kernel 3.11]

The Fedora 19 is installed in an ASUS TX300CA notebook, secure boot is off, [CSM (BIOS Compatibility Support Module)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Compatibility_Support_Module) mode is on.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

> A couple of years ago, Linus Torvalds was discussing Linux version
>   numbers and [said](https://www.linux.com/news/enterprise/biz-enterprise/485159-a-conversation-with-linus-torvalds), "I think I will call it 3.11 Linux for Workgroups."
>
> It turns out he wasn't joking. With a release candidate of Linux 3.11
>   now available, Torvalds has actually named the new version of the
>   kernel "[Linux for Workgroups](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ad81f0545ef01ea651886dddac4bef6cec930092/Makefile#L5)." He even gave it a Windows-themed boot
>   icon featuring Linux's mascot penguin, Tux, holding a flag emblazoned
>   with an old Windows logo. The name "Linux for Workgroups" follows such
>   whimsical past [Linux version names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_kernel_names) as "Pink Farting Weasel," "Killer
>   Bat of Doom," "Erotic Pickled Herring," and "Jeff Thinks I Should
>   Change This, But To What?"

From the news:
[20 years after Windows 3.11, Linus unveils “Linux for Workgroups”](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/07/20-years-after-windows-3-11-linus-unveils-linux-for-workgroups/)

Comment: i must say that i'm shocked by these version names

Comment: This did finally give an explanation for why he was so insistent that it was time to update the kernel version number to 3.x despite there not being any major changes of the sort that would normally justify incrementing the major version number.

Comment: Why isnt this logo use copyright infrigment and liable to 1 billion lawsuit?

Comment: @Fuqtard : maybe because parody is exempt from copyright law?

Comment: @DanNeely so possibly in 2021 there will be Kernel 5.1 named Linux XP?

Comment: It's not the real Windows logo, either: red/green and blue/yellow are switched.

Comment: @vsz I don’t think parody applies here (or at least, that it would hold up in court), there’s a very real chance of confusion, whereas parody only holds up when no such chance of confusion for the real product exists. Don’t get me wrong, I think it’s brilliant, and that Microsoft will probably not sue. But I also think that strictly speaking this isn’t covered by fair use / parody.

Comment: @AlvinWong Doubtful.  This is a funny once sort of joke; and AFAIK none of the Linux version name jokes have repeated themselves yet.

Comment: @vsz That's why MS would lose if they tried.  The reason they didn't file one anyway is that they only litigate for business reasons; not solely for lulz.  Off the record they're probably just as amused by the whole thing as everyone else.

Comment: @Fuqtard because [logos can't be copyrighted](http://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-protect.html#title), they can only be protected by trademarks. Also the trademark [must be renewed while in use every 10 years](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/expiration-trademark-registration-abandonment-37926.html) (Microsoft has not used that logo [seance vista](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-O3V7ruxzvxg/UPkuHMhrpOI/AAAAAAAABuY/BpZyLYxYWjg/s1600/Microsoft-Windows-logo-history.jpg)) then it is no longer protected.

Comment: "seance" - autocorrect I presume?  I don't think Vista is quite dead yet.

Answer (score 15):

It is because of the project name, "Linux for Workgroups", it is a reference for Windows 3.11 for Workgroups. I've found it quite interesting; I also found a reference [here](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/07/20-years-after-windows-3-11-linus-unveils-linux-for-workgroups/).

Comment: so, will this logo appears in whole 3.11 line, or just in the 3.11.0 version?

Comment: well, Linus Torvalds had reverted the logo to previous version. http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=d5d04bb48f0eb89c14e76779bb46212494de0bec

Comment: @LiuYan刘研 Oh, I'm really disappointed by this. Also he has changed the name to `Suicidal Squirrel` instead of the cool `Linux for Workgroups`

Answer (score 10):

It's a joke by Linus. This page: http://www.extremetech.com/computing/161426-linux-3-11-named-linux-for-workgroups-in-odd-homage-to-its-archenemy-windows gives more detail.

> Ever the prankster, Linus Torvalds has paid homage to Windows 3.11 by
>   naming Linux 3.11 “Linux for Workgroups.” Tux, Linux’s penguin mascot
>   that appears during boot-up, is now holding a Windows flag (pictured
>   above). This might seem a little odd, given Linux’s reputation as the
>   Windows antithesis, but Linux for Workgroups is actually one of
>   Linux’s saner names. Over the years, the Linux kernel has been
>   lumbered with some amazingly undignified designations, such as
>   Unicycling Gorilla, Erotic Pickled Herring, and Holy Dancing Manatees,
>   Batman!